# In React, how to render variable from a functional component?

Tags: reactjs, solidity

I am trying to make a counter that counts how many NFTs are minted.
I have an async function, getTotalTokensMinted, that gets the total number of tokens minted from a smart contract. How do I render the HTML so it displays the return value, numTokens, from getTotalTokensMinted? Should I use useState hook or local storage?

The code I have below returns a

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import './styles/App.css';
import myEpicNFT from './utils/MyEpicNFT.json';

const TOTAL_MINT_COUNT = 3;
const CONTRACTADDRESS = "0x6fe91f4814f372Eb40B547114CD75B76DF5f53dC";

const App = () => {

//const [NFTsMinted, NFTcounter] = useState(0);

 const getTotalTokensMinted = async () => {
   const { ethereum } = window;
   let numTokens;
   try {

     if (ethereum) {
       const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
       const signer = provider.getSigner();
       const connectedContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);

       numTokens = await connectedContract.getTokenNumber();
       return numTokens;
      } 
   } catch (error){
       console.log(error);
   }
   return(
     <div> {numTokens}</div>
   );
 }

return (
   <div className="App">
     <div className="container">
         <p className = "sub-text">
         NFT MINTED = {getTotalTokensMinted} / { TOTAL_MINT_COUNT }
         </p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 );


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code could quickly get confusing as you develop more functionality. As a rule of thumb, it's good to separate the business logic of your app from the UI.

Try putting your getTotalTokensMinted function in an /api folder or /utils. That function doesn't need to be a component; it simply needs to return a value...

```
const getTotalTokensMinted = async () => {
   const { ethereum } = window;
   let numTokens;
   try {

     if (ethereum) {
       const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
       const signer = provider.getSigner();
       const connectedContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);

       numTokens = await connectedContract.getTokenNumber();
       return numTokens;
      } 
        return null

   } catch (error){
       console.log(error);
   }
```

And then in the component you actually want to display the minted count you can simply declare a variable count (or whatever) which will store the number of tokens.

```
const App = () => {
const count = await getTotalTokensMinted();
return (
   <div className="App">
     <div className="container">
         <p className = "sub-text">
         NFT MINTED = {count} / { TOTAL_MINT_COUNT }
         </p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to get the function returned value like this

```
return (
   <div className="App">
     <div className="container">
         <p className = "sub-text">
         NFT MINTED = {getTotalTokensMinted()} / { TOTAL_MINT_COUNT }
         </p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 );
```

If you get an array object error you need to change on how you return the value in the function like this :

```
return (
    <div> {numTokens?.map((each)=>{
           <div>{each}</div>
           })}
   </div> 
)
```

Comment: I tried that, but I got an 

Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: @EmilyKuo I've edited the question based on your error please accept answer If it helped you in anyway .

Answer (score 0):

From react point of view you want some async operation and its output in DOM. According to provided code snippet you are calling `getTotalTokensMinted` in the DOM with incorrect syntax. As a solution you need to call async function in `useEffect` hook with no dependency to render as `componentDidMount`. You need local state to store result and then use that state in the DOM.

### Steps

Follow these steps as a solution

#### Define local state

By using `useState` you can create local state. You can use global state depends on the requirement

```
const [NFTsMinted, setNFTsMinted] = useState(0);
```

#### Async function

Set state in async function as follow

```
const getTotalTokensMinted = async () => {
    const { ethereum } = window;
    
    if (ethereum) {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      const connectedContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);

      const numTokens = await connectedContract.getTokenNumber();
      setNFTsMinted(numTokens)
    } 
  }
```

#### Call async function

Use useEffect hook to call function

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getTotalTokensMinted()
  }, [])
```

#### Display results in DOM

Use state variable to display counts

```
<div className="App">
  <div className="container">
    <p className = "sub-text">
      NFT MINTED = {NFTsMinted} / { TOTAL_MINT_COUNT }
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah I tried that, but I got "Objects are not valid as a React child" error. I think it is something when I incorporated the getTotalTokensMinted in useEffect. I am trying to persist the numTokens value even when the browser refreshes and wouldn't it reset to zero if useState is initialized to zero?

Comment: Can you show me what is stored in `NFTsMinted ` after fetching? You can console by writing `console.log(numTokens)` above `setNFTsMinted(numTokens)`. Second thing if you want to see results after refreshing then you should store this numTokens in cookies or local storage you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie for storing cookies

Comment: Possibly you are not getting correct (number) type from `getTokenNumber()` function

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your component in the proper syntax:

example:
<Route exact path="/" element={Home}

Will give you this same error...Need to correct to this:

<Route exact path="/" element={}